# Regex for values with specific conditions

Tags: regex

I want to write the regex for values separated by ',': (I need to write a validator)

Valid:

```
mala, maka, make, top
value1
value1, value2
1, 2
test-1, test-3
```

Invalid:

```
ma la, maka, make, top
mala, maka, (space)
mala, maka,
mala,maka
(space), jkkk
, value
```

I tried several combinations, but I couldn't achieve the final result.

Regex: `/^\w(\s*,?\s*\w)*$/`

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with the result? Maybe you could just `split` and `trim`?

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular/Typescript?

Comment: @eol I need to write a validator in Angular

Comment: Use this `^(?!\s)(\w+)$` and join on comma. See demo https://regex101.com/r/wK9MQ1/12

Comment: If you want the match only you can omit the capturing groups and the `{1}` is also not necessary. `^(?:[a-z0-9]+,)*[a-z0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/Xx5LND/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to allow special characters in between (except comma) and white space should not be allowed

Comment: @MoannaTabala You could try it like this, listing an the chars that you consider special in the character class `^(?:[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+-]+, )*[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+-]+$` https://regex101.com/r/IRibr4/1

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird Just a question, isn't there any short way to allow all characters except comma and space in the values in between, or I have to define them?

Comment: @MoannaTabala Yes there is `^(?:[^\s,]+, )*[^\s,]+$` https://regex101.com/r/vK1oEr/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could exclude any char except a whitespace char or a comma and repeat that 1+ times. At the end match a single space (As `\s` can also possibly match a newline) and then repeat that 0+ times to match optional preceding occurrences.

End the pattern with matching at least 1 time 1+ occurrences of any char except a comma or whitespace char.

```
^(?:[^\s,]+, )*[^\s,]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\s,]+,`  Match 1+ times any char except whitespace char or comma followed by matching a space
- `)*` Close the group and repeat it 0+ times
- `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except a whitespace char or comma
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK1oEr/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a non-capturing group for the characters and the comma and let this group repeat an arbitrary number of times and then end with the characters only (see [test-cases)](https://regex101.com/r/oUWu2P/2):

```
  /^(?:[^\s]+, )*[^\s,]+$/ig
```

Comment: But I need space after comma and before the beginning of a new value. This does not even allow the space after comma

Comment: I've updated the solution, can you check again please?

Comment: It works! Thank you! Just one case is missing. I don't want to allow spaces in between and numbers, special characters should be possible too

Comment: But @The fourth bird was faster - so you should accept her/his answer :)